# MSAL TokenAcquisition from the token stored in the file

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token

I have saved initial usertakencache in a file. Now when I want to acquire the AcquireTokenSilent, I dont know how to use that saved token cache because all the documentation I find are used on the basis of cache but not for other memory formats.

I have searched on number of microsoft MSAL repos but they do not provide any help with the solution.

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication app = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\Test.txt");
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

                var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            string[] scopes = { "Mail.Read" };


            try
            {
                // try to get token silently
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                ViewBag.Relogin = "true";
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception eee)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "An error has occurred. Details: " + eee.Message;
                return View();
            }

            if (result != null)
            {
                // Use the token to read email
                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
                hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);
                HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages");

                string rez = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ViewBag.Message = rez;
            }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: Actually I am storing the accessToken in file so I cannot retrieve data from 
 await app.GetAccountsAsync()
As it only gets data from cache so I dont know what to do.

Comment: The token is required for the call to the graph api, which you are providing. AcquireTokenSilent internally creates a cache for the token and uses that (see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) - you don't have to worry about doing this. So as far as i can see, your code is correct ?